# Java string with name of class to class

Tags: java, reflection

Sorry about the strange topic name, could not find one that fitted well.
To my problem, i want to create something dynamic in Java, it is a very simple class that can take an event and throw it along, sadly have the system i am using be made so each event must have it own method where the event is the argument of the method, but the good news is that we can add as many event listener classes as we want! I wan my program to be able to dynamic add and remove the methods that are being listened to, by add and remove the listen classes.

I am not good with Java but have a fair deal expirence with C#, so i attacked my problem as i would there and created this class.

```
public class TESPluginDynListener<T> implements Listener {

    TESPlugin plugin;

    public TESPluginDynListener(TESPlugin plugin){
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }

    @EventHandler(ignoreCancelled=false, priority = EventPriority.LOW)
    public void onDynEvent(T event){
        if(event instanceof Event)
            plugin.onEvent((Event)event);
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine, but my problem is, that the event i have to register do i get as a String, example "some.package.someEvent", and i have no idea how to translate that into the Type T so i can add the listener class.

So how can i create an instance my class TESPluginDynListener where T is translated from a String? I am not interested in doing a lot of if else, as i want this to be as dynamic as possible!

Here is an idea of what i am trying to do

```
String eventClass = "some.package.someEvent";

TESPluginDynListener listener = new TESPluginDynListener<Type.FromName(eventClass)>(this);
eventhandeler.RegisterListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [`Class.forName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) and [`Class.newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29).

On the other hand, bear in mind that type erasure in generics means you don't really need to know `T` in order to build a `TESPluginDynListener`... you probably want to take `Class<T>` in the constructor for `TESPluginDynListener` and use [`Class.isInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29) rather than `instanceof` within `onDynEvent`.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the implementation? i have  tryed but can not really see how to implement it!

Comment: @DoomStone: It's not clear where you're trying to do what, to be honest, which makes it very hard to give you an example. I would be very tempted to make `TESPluginDynListener` non-generic given that the generics won't really be useful at execution time. That's likely to simplify your life significantly.

Comment: I have tryed to make a little example of what i want to do, in my question. "new TESPluginDynListener<eventClass.GetType()>(this);" is basicly what i need help with

Comment: @DoomStone: That's my point - you can't provide type arguments at execution time. Get rid of the generics - they're not doing you any good.

Comment: Sadly i just can't do Event or Object, it has to be the class itself or else wont it work :(

Comment: Well without any more context, I can't help you any further. But trying to use generics when you only know the type at execution time is just not terribly useful.

Comment: I am not saying that it is! but that is sadly the only way to do it!

Comment: @DoomStone: So you say, but with no explanation. I'm not sure how you expect me to be able to help you at this point. I suggest you read the Java generics FAQ, particularly the section on type erasure: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ100